# Get the height of a DIV where the parent DIV has position absolute (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my webpage, there is a `div.content` container with `position: absolute`. Inside the parent div (`div.content`) there is a `div.sub_content`.
I want to extract the `.sub_content` height using JavaScript, or JQuery.

In the program I need to calculate the `div.sub_content` *height*.

**I'm using the below code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = $('div.content div.sub_content').height();
    alert(a);
});
```

Comment: show your html please

Comment: As I can see from the code you shared, Jquery Selector is the culprit. your selector does not return the desired object, that is why height() method did not returned the expected output. Anyway, @לבנימלכה answer is clear and correct.

Comment: If the element is dynamically styled you may need to get the computed style.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('.content .sub_content').height();`

See example with `height` in css and without...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var a = $('.content .sub_content').height();
var b = $('.content .sub_content_noHeight').height();
alert('sub_content: ' + a + '  sub_content_noHeight: ' + b);
});
```

```css
.content{
position:absolute;
}
.sub_content{
height:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="sub_content">
  With height property in css
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="sub_content_noHeight">
  Without height property in css
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .sub_content should not mentioned the height